# Do the procedure used to find the empirical formula from combustion analysis be extended in other cases when is not specifically mentioned?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, elemental-analysis

The situation is as follows:

> A sample of $\pu{19.40 g}$ from a certain compound consisting only in $\ce{K, Cr}$ and $\ce{O}$, receives a treatment. This gives $\pu{7.6 g}$ of $\ce{Cr2O3}$ and $\pu{9.70 g}$ of the compound is transformed into $\pu{13.85 g}$ of $\ce{KClO4}$. Using this information find the empirical formula.

In this particular situation there isn't given any specification on what sort of treatment the sample received. Given such situation, can the steps used in finding the empirical formula during combustion analysis be used as well?.

Typically in the mentioned scenario (combustion analysis) a mass of the sample is given (as in the problem).

After that the sample is burned in oxygen. From this we determine the masses of the combustion products $\ce{CO2}$, $\ce{H2O}$, $\ce{N2}$, $\ce{SO2}$ and using this mass we'll find the number of moles of each combustion product and use the atomic masses to calculate the masses of the elements other than oxygen in the original sample.

Such mass is found by subtracting the mass of the sample to that of the combined mass of the other combustion products. Later, percentages can be used to a $100\,g$ sample to find the number of moles of $\ce{C}$, $\ce{H}$, $\ce{N}$ and $\ce{S}$. Then all is left to divide the moles of each element by the moles of elements present in the smallest ammount. In the last step only is needed a multiplication by non integral ratios as necessary to give small whole numbers.

Using the same logic I've attempted to solve this riddle, but would that be also applicable to any sort of problem involving finding the empirical formula?.

First I did found the grams of Chromium in the given $\pu{7.6 g}$.

Assuming FW for $\ce{Cr2O3} = 2(52)+3(16)=\pu{152 gmol-1}$

$\pu{7.6 g}\,\ce{Cr2O3} \times \frac{2\times \pu{52 g}\,\ce{Cr}}{\pu{152 g}\,\ce{Cr2O3}}=\pu{5.2 g}\,\ce{Cr}$

FW for $\ce{KClO4} = 39+35.5+4(16)= \pu{138.5 g mol-1}$

Then:

$\pu{13.85 g}\,\ce{KClO4} \times \frac{1\times \pu{39 g}\,\ce{K}}{\pu{138.5 g}\,\ce{KClO4}}=\pu{3.9 g}\,\ce{K}$

Then the rest of the mass should be the oxygen, subtracted from the sample:

$19.40-(3.9+5.2)=10.3$

Therefore the moles for each would be as follows:

$\pu{5.2 g}\,\ce{Cr}\times \frac{\pu{1 mol}\,\ce{Cr}}{\pu{52 g}\,\ce{Cr}}=\pu{0.1 mol}\,\ce{Cr}$

$\pu{3.9 g}\,\ce{K}\times \frac{\pu{1 mol}\,\ce{K}}{\pu{39 g}\,\ce{K}}=\pu{0.1 mol}\,\ce{K}$

$\pu{10.3 g}\,\ce{O}\times \frac{\pu{1 mol}\,\ce{O}}{\pu{16 g}\,\ce{O}}=\pu{6.4375 mol}\,\ce{O}$

Dividing between the smallest yields:

$\frac{\pu{0.1 mol}\,\ce{Cr}}{0.1}=1$

$\frac{\pu{0.1 mol}\,\ce{K}}{0.1}=1$

$\frac{\pu{6.4375 mol}\,\ce{O}}{0.1}=6.4375$

Which would give:

$\ce{K1Cr1O_{6.4375}}$

However this isn't very convincing to me. However since the chromium and potassium are in the same proportion it looks very suspiciously to be potassium dichromate. But does it exist a justification for this. Can somebody help me to clear out the basis for the right calculation?. The most importantly **what should be subtracted and from where**?.

Comment: The wording is ambiguous and potentially misleading. Confirm two things with the source: 1) That the compound contains only K, Cr, O or some other atoms might be there and 2) should you read that 19.40 g produce 7.6 g of Cr2O3 and 13.85 g KClO4 or that 19.40 g produce 7.6 g of Cr2O3 and 9.7 g of the compound produce 13.85 g of KClO4 .

Comment: @permeakra The source implies that such compound has **only** K, Cr and O. I became confused at how exactly should I understand those $9.7\,g$ of the compound.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the exercise you are discussing is no sufficiently well-defined to give an unambiguous answer. It would help to cite the source of the exercise.

Comment: @KarstenTheis This question comes from a collection of riddles with no author so I dont know exactly how I can met the criteria you are asking. The original source is not in english and I had to translate it the closest possible to the original text, but I will review it to update this question.

Comment: @KarstenTheis I've already updated the question and corrected any misleading clue in the question and added what was being asked. As it stands now the question is well defined with what is requested in this community.

Answer (score 0):

I made a different approach. I transform the second experiment in such a way that the same amount of the initial compound $\ce{K_xCr_yO_z}$ is used in both experiments. As the second experiment uses exactly one half of what was used in the first, I can simplify both data in saying that 19.4 g of the compound react with something containing at least Cl to produce 7.6 g $\ce{Cr2O3}$ and 27.718 g $\ce{KClO4}$. In moles, it produces 0.05 mole $\ce{Cr2O3}$ and 0.2 mole $\ce{KClO4}$. 0.2 is 4 times 0.05. So the equation must be something like :

...  +  ... -> $\ce{Cr2O3}$  + 4  $\ce{KClO4}$

On the other hand 19.4 g is exactly 0.1 mole of $\ce{K2CrO4}$. Furthermore, 0.1 mol $\ce{K2CrO4}$ produces exactly 0.05 mol $\ce{Cr2O3}$ whatever its reaction. So the equation is probably :

2 $\ce{K2CrO4}$  +  ....   ->  $\ce{Cr2O3}$  +  4 $\ce{KClO4}$

By subtracting atoms in the equation, one finds that the mysterious missing substance must contain 4 Chlorine atom plus (19 - 8 =) 11 atoms Oxygen. It might be $\ce{Cl4O11}$. But, in my opinion, this does not seem reasonable.

Another way of handling the problem is to weigh for both experiment the amount of the mysterious substance. It is :  7.6 + 27.7 - 19.4 = 15.918 g. Surprisingly enough, this mass is exactly equal to 0.05 mol $\ce{Cl4O11}$. So the equation is :

2 $\ce{K2CrO4}$ + $\ce{Cl4O11}$  --> $\ce{Cr2O3}$ +  4 $\ce{KClO4}$

There must be a mistake somewhere, because I seriously doubt that $\ce{Cl4O11}$  exist. Never heard of this strange molecule !! Or maybe it is a mixture of existing molecules like $\ce{Cl2O7}$  +  2 $\ce{ClO2}$ .. Who knows ?

I would be pleased to hear any sensible reaction to my odd calculations.

Comment: You should probably try K2Cr2O7, or perhaps don't wate time on such vague question. What is "treatment" there? I doubt if values even need to add up.

Comment: K2Cr2O7 does not work. It yields non integers as coefficients

Comment: @Maurice Interesting observation. How do you come to the conclusion that potassium dichromate does not yield integers can you show this?.

Comment: $$\ce{4K2CrO4 + 4Cl2 + 11O2 -> 2Cr2O3 + 8KClO4}$$ would work.

Answer (score 0):

**OP's question:**

> A sample of $\pu{19.40 g}$ of a certain compound containing $\ce{K, Cr}$ and $\ce{O}$, receives a treatment. This gives $\pu{7.60 g}$ of $\ce{Cr2O3}$ and $\pu{9.70 g}$ of the compound is transformed into $\pu{13.85 g}$ of $\ce{KClO4}$.

And then, OP has wonder, given only above information where *no other information* is given regarding how to solve it, which would be the most adequate way to find the empirical formula of such compound. And somehow, OP has taken a correct approach to solve the problem, but lost in close to the end of it. I'd put an answer using OP's approach and showing where OP assume wrong:

I assumed the molecular formula of original compound is $\ce{K_xCr_yO_z}$. First, OP found the amount of $\ce{Cr}$ in the given $\pu{19.40 g}$ of $\ce{K_xCr_yO_z}$ using the first given information (OP has worded it wrong but done the correct calculation). The first information given is: When $\pu{19.40 g}$ of a certain compound containing $\ce{K, Cr}$ and $\ce{O}$ is treated in certain way, it would give $\pu{7.60 g}$ of $\ce{Cr2O3}$. Actually, $\ce{Cr}$ contains in this $\pu{7.60 g}$ of $\ce{Cr2O3}$ is equal to $\ce{Cr}$ contains in $\pu{19.40 g}$ of $\ce{K_xCr_yO_z}$, if the conversion is $100\%$.

Also, OP should know that formula weight of $\ce{Cr2O3}$ is $\pu{151.99 gmol-1}$ (This is a fact so does not have to assume it). Hence:

$$\pu{7.60 g}\text{ of }\ce{Cr2O3} \times \frac{2\times \pu{52.0 g}\text{ of } \ce{Cr}}{\pu{151.99 g}\text{ of }\ce{Cr2O3}}=\pu{5.20 g}\text{ of }\ce{Cr}\\ (\text{this is the amount of $\ce{Cr}$ in $\pu{19.40 g}$ of $\ce{K_xCr_yO_z}$})$$

This can also be used to find the mass of $\ce{Cr}$ in $\pu{1.00 g}$ of $\ce{K_xCr_yO_z}$ at this point if needed:

$$\frac{\pu{5.20 g}\text{ of }\ce{Cr}}{\pu{19.40 g} \text{ of } \ce{K_xCr_yO_z}} = \pu{0.268 g} \text{ of }\ce{Cr} \text{ in } \pu{1.00 g}\text{ of }\ce{K_xCr_yO_z}$$

Keep in mind that the usefulness of this unit value is evidence in the calculations of the next step.

Second, OP correctly found the amount of $\ce{K}$ in $\pu{9.70 g}$ of $\ce{K_xCr_yO_z}$, using the second given information. The second information given is: When treated, $\pu{9.70 g}$ of original compound ($\ce{K_xCr_yO_z}$) gives $\pu{13.85 g}$ of $\ce{KClO4}$. However, it seems, OP has wrongly assumed that the amount of $\ce{KClO4}$ given here is for $\pu{19.40 g}$ of $\ce{K_xCr_yO_z}$ used in first conversion. Actually, amount of $\ce{K}$ contains in this $\pu{13.85 g}$ of $\ce{KClO4}$ is equal to $\ce{K}$ contains in only $\pu{9.70 g}$ of $\ce{K_xCr_yO_z}$, assuming the conversion is $100\%$ again.

Again, the formula weight of $\ce{KClO4}$ can be found in online easily, which is $\pu{138.55 g mol-1}$. Now, we can plug in the values as follows:

$$\pu{13.85 g}\text{ of }\ce{KClO4} \times \frac{1\times \pu{39 g}\text{ of }\ce{K}}{\pu{138.55 g}\text{ of }\ce{KClO4}}=\pu{3.90 g}\text{ of }\ce{K} \\ (\text{this is the amount of $\ce{K}$ in $\pu{9.70 g}$ of $\ce{K_xCr_yO_z}$})$$

For convenience, let's use this value to find the mass of $\ce{K}$ in $\pu{1.00 g}$ of $\ce{K_xCr_yO_z}$:

$$\frac{\pu{3.90 g}\text{ of }\ce{K}}{\pu{9.70 g} \text{ of } \ce{K_xCr_yO_z}} = \pu{0.402 g} \text{ of }\ce{K} \text{ in } \pu{1.00 g}\text{ of }\ce{K_xCr_yO_z}$$

At this point, thinking above calculated ${\pu{3.90 g}\text{ of }\ce{K}}$ is from $\pu{19.40 g} $ of $ \ce{K_xCr_yO_z}$, OP has wrongfully assumed that the rest of the mass in $\pu{19.40 g}$ of $\ce{K_xCr_yO_z}$ is oxygen. Simply, what OP should have done is make a simple conversion to find the correct amount of $\ce{K}$ in $\pu{19.40 g}$ of $\ce{K_xCr_yO_z}$:

$$\text{The amount of $\ce{K}$ in $\pu{19.40 g}$ of $\ce{K_xCr_yO_z}$}\\=\pu{3.90 g}\text{ of }\ce{K} \times \frac{\pu{19.40 g} \text{ of }\ce{K_xCr_yO_z}}{\pu{9.70 g} \text{ of }\ce{K_xCr_yO_z}}\\=\pu{7.80 g}\text{ of }\text{of } \ce{K} $$

Or, you can simply multiply above unit value ($\pu{0.402 g} \text{ of }\ce{K} \text{ in } \pu{1.00 g} \text{ of }\ce{K_xCr_yO_z}$) by $\pu{19.40 g}$: $0.402 \times 19.40 = 7.8$.

Now, it is safe to assume rest of $\pu{19.40 g}$ is $\ce{O}$, since the compound contains only $\ce{K, Cr}$, and $\ce{O}$. Thus, you can subtract to find the amount of $\ce{O}$ in $\pu{19.40 g}$ of $\ce{K_xCr_yO_z}$ as follows:

$\text{The amount of $\ce{O}$ in $\pu{19.40 g}$ of $\ce{K_xCr_yO_z}$} =\pu{19.40 g}- \pu{(7.80 + 5.20) g} = \pu{6.40 g}$

Now, the easiest way to calculate formula is as follows:

$$\text{The mass ratio of $\ce{K:Cr:O}$ in $\pu{19.40 g}$ of $\ce{K_xCr_yO_z}$} = \pu{7.80 g}: \pu{5.20 g}:\pu{6.40 g}$$

$$\text{The mole ratio of $\ce{K:Cr:O}$ in $\pu{19.40 g}$ of $\ce{K_xCr_yO_z}$ }(x:y:z)\\ = \frac{\pu{7.80 g}}{\pu{39.10 gmol-1}}: \frac{\pu{5.20 g}}{\pu{52.00 gmol-1}}:\frac{\pu{6.40 g}}{\pu{16.00 gmol-1}} \\=\pu{0.2 mol}:\pu{0.1 mol}:\pu{0.4 mol} \\=\pu{2 mol}:\pu{1 mol}:\pu{4 mol}$$

This ratio would give the molecular formula: $\ce{K2CrO4}$.

Comment: I'm really sorry for any word which has not been used accurately and may had caused any misconception, but the original source did not helped much neither. Btw, when I mentioned **assuming** I intended to say that I'm rounding the masses for the atoms $K$, $Cl$ and $O$ to their nearest integers or least decimals. I'm well aware that this is a fact. I'm a bit lost about the conversion factor. How exactly should I understand $\frac{\textrm{19.40 g}\,\textrm{K}_x\textrm{Cr}_y\textrm{O}_z}{\textrm{9.70 g}\,\textrm{K}_x\textrm{Cr}_y\textrm{O}_z}$?

Comment: Does it imply $\textrm{19.40 g}\,\textrm{K}_x\textrm{Cr}_y\textrm{O}_z= \textrm{9.70 g}\,\textrm{K}_x\textrm{Cr}_y\textrm{O}_z$? Why the $5.2\,g\,\textrm{Cr}$ is the same in quantity that in the sample and a conversion factor **must** be used for the $3.9\,g\,\textrm{K}$. Aren't those grams the same what is in the sample?. I am getting the idea that in the passage is stressed that $19.40\,g$ of the compound is transformed totally into $Cr_{2}O_{3}$? But when it mentions $9.70\,g$ of the compound is transformed into $\textrm{KClO}_{4}$.

Comment: Doesn't mean that $19.40-9.70=9.70$ is transformed in $\textrm{Cr}_{2}\textrm{O}_{3}$? and a conversion factor must be used for $\textrm{Cr}$ as well?. Can you explain this part to me please?

Comment: It is a mathematical ratio, you learned from algebra: If $2x$ has $4y$s, then how many $y$s in $20x$? To solve it, find how many $y$s in $1x$: $\frac{4y}{2x}=2y$ per $x$. This is the unit. Then multifly it by $20x$ to find the answer, which is $40$ $y$s.

Comment: Yes I know it is a ratio. I think the part where I got confused is *why* should be considered a ratio. Perhaps is due this is meant to concentration and this is preserved constantly to the whole substance. Therefore the ratio can be used.

Comment: In, real problem, $\pu{9.7 g}$ of $\ce{K_xCr_yO_z}$ gives $\pu{3.9 g}$ of $\ce{K}$ so to find how many $\pu{g}$ of  $\ce{K}$ in $\pu{1.0 g}$ of $\ce{K_xCr_yO_z}$, you divide: $\frac{3.9}{9.7} = 0.402$ (this is the unit means per gram of your compound).  Now, to find $\pu{g}$ of  $\ce{K}$ in $\pu{19.40 g}$ of $\ce{K_xCr_yO_z}$, you multify: $0.402 \times 19.40 = 7.8$.

Comment: Can you upgrade your last comment as part of your answer?. I think it is very relevant as means of clearing doubts of the meaning in conversion units. There's an unanswered doubt which is regarding why **subtraction** must be made to find the oxygen?. It doesn't **say** specifically that it is a combustion analysis. I'm assuming that since oxygen is a gas it is measured indirectly as it is not collected as a solid given the salt and the oxide mentioned in the problem. Am I right with this assumption?.

Comment: My answer is updated as you requested.

Comment: Formatting note: please avoid using "textual formulas" where unit symbols are followed by text of chemical formulas. This is incorrect, makes parsing harder and leads to strange results such as $\pu{3.90 g K}$ which reads as 3.90 gram-kelvin.

Comment: @andselisk: Corrected all possible ones as suggested.

Comment: I also meant there should be no prepositions as well, it's better to keep textual explanation to the preceding or following *text paragraph* and use symbols and labels for the formulas. For example, instead of $$\pu{7.60 g}\text{ of }\ce{Cr2O3} \times \frac{2\times \pu{52.0 g}\text{ of } \ce{Cr}}{\pu{151.99 g}\text{ of }\ce{Cr2O3}}=\pu{5.20 g}\text{ of }\ce{Cr}\\ (\text{this is the amount of $\ce{Cr}$ in $\pu{19.40 g}$ of $\ce{K_xCr_yO_z}$})$$ in my opinion it would be more correct to use the following:

Comment: Mass of chromium $m(\ce{Cr})$ in $\pu{19.40 g}$ of $\ce{K_xCr_yO_z}$:
$$m(\ce{Cr}) = m(\ce{Cr2O3})×\frac{2 × m(\ce{Cr})}{m(\ce{Cr2O3})} = \pu{7.60 g} × \frac{2 × \pu{52.0 g}}{\pu{151.99 g}} = \pu{5.20 g}$$

Answer (score 0):

The "riddle" as translated by the OP reads:

> A sample of 19.40 g of a certain compound containing K,Cr and O, receives a treatment. This gives 7.60 g of Cr2O3 and 9.70 g of the compound is transformed into 13.85 g of KClO4.

In the answer by Mathew Mahindaratne, this is interpreted as (I paraphrase):

1. 19.40 g of a compound containing K, Cr and O exclusively reacts to form 7.60 g of $\ce{Cr2O3}$. In this reaction, the amount of chromium in reactant and product are equal (i.e. there is no other reactant or product containing chromium, and the yield is 100%).
2. 9.70 g of the same starting material reacts to form 13.85 g of $\ce{KClO4}$. Likewise, the amount of potassium in reactant and product are equal (i.e. there is no other reactant or product containing chromium, and the yield is 100%).

Without giving the numerical answer, I will sketch how you could solve this:

- Find the mass percentages of chromium and potassium in the original compound. First, calculate the mass of these elements in the product from mass of the product using the known composition. Then, divide by the mass of the reactant to get the mass percentage.
- Calculate the missing mass percentage of oxygen (percentages have to add up to 100%). Then, proceed as you would usually to get the empirical formula from the mass percentages.

For the numerical answer, work through the correct answer by Mathew Mahindaratne.